# Let $H\le G$. Is it the case that for any $x,y\in G$, if $xy\in H$, then $yx\in H$?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

This is **Exercise 88** of Rose's, *"A Course on Group Theory"*. [This Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24H%5Cunlhd%20G%24%2C%20and%2C%20%24x%2Cy%5Cin%20G%24%2C%20such%20that%2C%20%24xy%5Cin%20H%24%2C%20then%2C%20%24yx%5Cin%20H%24&p=1) was inconclusive due to too many mathematical terms. [This MSE search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgroup-theory%5D+rose+88) returned nothing.

*I have answered my question in typing this up. Now that I've put it together, though, I reckon it's worth sharing so that others may benefit; I could also have made a mistake. It'd help to see a different proof/solution, too, I suppose.*

### The Question:

> Suppose $H\unlhd G$. Show that if $x$ and $y$ are elements of $G$ such that $xy\in H$, then $yx\in H$. *Would this be true merely on the hypothesis that $H\le G$?* [Emphasis added.]

### Thoughts:

I think normality of $H$ in $G$ is necessary.

---

Suppose $H\unlhd G$. Let $x,y\in G$ such that $xy\in H$. By normality, $H=yHy^{-1}$, so, in particular, $y(xy)y^{-1}=yx\in H$.

---

Now suppose $H\le G$ but $H\not\lhd G$. Let $a,b\in G$ such that $ab\in H$.

My first thought is that, if there is a counterexample, such a group $G$ must not be abelian, since otherwise $ba=ab\in H$ trivially. Also, $a\neq b^{-1}$ and *vice versa*.

This led me to consider the smallest nonabelian group $S_3\cong D_3$, the dihedral group of order $6$. If we let $H=\{{\rm id}, (12)\}$, maybe we could get somewhere. Nothing leaps out at me as an obvious choice of $a,b$ as above; we would need $ab=(12)$ and $ba\in\{(13), (23), (123), (321)\}$; so let's try, based on experience, $a=(123), b=(23)$; then $ab=(123)(23)=(12)\in H$ and $ba=(23)(123)=(13)\notin H$.

Thus normality is necessary.

---

Do you have an alternative approach?

Please help :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "Let $a,b\in G$ such that $ab\in H$", that doesn't exploit the explicit non-normality of $H$. You want to get right on that from the start. For instance, if you instead say:

> Let $a\in G$ be such that $aH\neq Ha$.

Then the proof is over in two short sentences:

> Let $b\in aH\setminus Ha$. Then $a^{-1}b\in H$, but $ba^{-1}\notin H$.

Comment: One might conceivably worry that $aH\setminus Ha=\varnothing$. But then because $aH\neq Ha$ we must necessarily have $Ha\setminus aH\neq\varnothing$, and the proof continues with the products turned around.

Comment: Thank you, @Arthur :)

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the following holds.

Let$H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then the following are equivalent. 
(a) For all $x,y \in G$ with $xy \in H$, also $yx \in H$.
(b) $H \unlhd G$.

Proof (a) $\implies$ (b): let $h \in H$, $x \in G$, then $(hx)x^{-1}=h \in H$. Hence $x^{-1}hx \in H$.
(b) $\implies$ (a): if $x, y \in G$ with $xy \in H$, then $x^{-1}(xy)x=yx \in H$, since $H$ is normal.